# SSRS: Can't remove whitespace when hiding Tablixes or Rectangles

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am creating a report which contains tables at the top and bottom that are always visible. However, between these are 12 tablixes which optionally appear based on the existence of data for them. When they do not exist there is a considerable amount of whitespace in the middle section of the report which makes the report look awful.

I've tried two strategies to fix this:

1. Set up one rectangle to hold all tablixes. Set all tablixes to have the hidden property set to be true if CountRows() < 1. Leave no gaps in between the tablixes so as to not leave cumulative gaps.
2. Set up one rectangle per tablix. Set all rectangles and all tablixes to have the hidden property set to be true if CountRows(dataset for tablix) < 1. Leave no gaps in between the rectangles so as to not leave cumulative gaps.

I can think of no other setting to rid the report of gaps for hidden tables.

Answer (score 1):

How about a table with separate rows that contains all your tablixes (tabli?) .

Hide the row based on the tablix's no data condition.

It doesn't help for left to right though since hiding a column leaves space.

Comment: Then we can't set different datasources for tables, can we?

Answer (score 1):

So, I noticed that there were warnings about overlapping objects. I went back through and removed overlaps and my report did much better at reducing white space. It's not perfect, but acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Overlapping objects screw up the whitespace on reports! I don't get any warnings about overlapping objects but I tried adjusting the report to ensure no objects were overlapping and it fixes the whitespacing issues without the need for tables!